# Atom gpp-compiler is giving "'C:\Users\adminUser' is not recognized as an internal or..." error

Tags: c++, atom-editor, compiler-warnings

Whenever I try to compile and run a hello world C++ program I just get a command prompt with the error `'C:\Users\adminUser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.
[A picture of the command prompt error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NDaZ.png)

I tried adding and taking away the gpp-compiler from the user PATH. Unfortunately, that didn't work. Thanks in advance for any help.

This is the code I am trying to compile and run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At a guess you have a space in your username. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: A minimal reproducible example of the code I compiled?

Comment: You should turn on the echo for the command it is trying to run.  You may have to add quotes or a path separation character in the command portion of the call.

Comment: What is the echo? I'm not familiar with that term.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure

- **"C:\MinGW\bin"** & **"C:\MinGW"** Register on Path
- Check the c/c++ file not use **symbol** Otherwise Rename it